# ApyCom JavaScript jQuery menu - how to show the currently selected navigation element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation

I'm using ApyCom's jQuery navigation menu.  It's working fine except when I click on a different navigation element, I expect that navigation element to remain highlighted to tell the user what page they're on. What's weird is if I replace the `href` value from an actual page (Contact.aspx, for example) to `#`, the selected element stays highlighted (of course, then I can't navigate to Contact.aspx because all it has is a `#`).  It's only when I replace the `#` with an actual page is when this funkiness happens.  Here's a screenshot of the Default.aspx page:

[image]

Now here's a picture of the Contact.aspx page (Contact Us):

[image]

Notice that "Home" is still highlighted.  Here's my menu mark-up for the Contact.aspx page:

```
            <div id="menu">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="Default.aspx" class="parent"><span>Home</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Services</span></a>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Sub Item 1</span></a>
                                    <div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.1</span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.2</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Sub Item 2</span></a>
                                    <div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 2.1</span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 2.2</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 3</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 4</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 5</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 6</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 7</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="About.aspx"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="Contact.aspx"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put `class="current"` on my `<li>` item.  This resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

`class="current"` in `<li>` will not work.

Instead of `class="current"`, you need to put `class="active"` in your `<li>` section.

Below is the example:

```
<li class="active">
```